# Creating a CollisionObject from a mesh in Hydro

Tags: ros, c++, collision-object, mesh

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to create create a collision object from a [mesh resource](http://moveit.ros.org/doxygen/namespaceshapes.html#af2fafa8168f92f2ed5c9ae3748d0f032) and am having trouble understanding how to pass an enumerated type to a message constructor:

```
const shapes::Mesh* navstar_shape = shapes::createMeshFromResource("package://altius_arm/meshes/NAVSTAR_GPS_Satellite.dae");
shape_msgs::Mesh navstar_mesh;
shapes::constructMsgFromShape(navstar_shape,navstar_mesh);
navstar_collision_object.meshes[0] = navstar_mesh;
```

I get the following compiler error:

```
/home/peter/ros/altius_ws/src/altius_arm/src/servo_capture.cpp: In constructor ‘ServoCapture::ServoCapture()’:
/home/peter/ros/altius_ws/src/altius_arm/src/servo_capture.cpp:77:61: error: invalid initialization of reference of type ‘shapes::ShapeMsg& {aka boost::variant<shape_msgs::SolidPrimitive_<std::allocator<void> >, shape_msgs::Mesh_<std::allocator<void> >, shape_msgs::Plane_<std::allocator<void> > >&}’ from expression of type ‘shape_msgs::Mesh’
/opt/ros/hydro/include/geometric_shapes/shape_operations.h:62:6: error: in passing argument 2 of ‘bool shapes::constructMsgFromShape(const shapes::Shape*, shapes::ShapeMsg&)’
```

I thought constructMsgFromShape was asking for the message object by reference, but it didn't work so I tried passing it by address which at least gets the compiler to realize that I'm passing the right typedef but gives a similar error. Does anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/147886/creating-a-collisionobject-from-a-mesh-in-hydro/) by [St3am](https://answers.ros.org/users/6506/st3am/) on ROS Answers with karma: 170 on 2014-04-02

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
shapes::Mesh* navstar_shape = shapes::createMeshFromResource("package://altius_arm/meshes/NAVSTAR_GPS_Satellite.dae");
shape_msgs::Mesh navstar_mesh;
shapes::ShapeMsg navstar_mesh_msg = navstar_mesh;
shapes::constructMsgFromShape(navstar_shape,navstar_mesh_msg);
navstar_collision_object.meshes[0] = navstar_mesh;
navstar_collision_object.mesh_poses[0] = navstar_pose;
navstar_collision_object_topic = node.advertise<moveit_msgs::CollisionObject>("collision_object",0);
```

Using a templated typedef solves it, props to [Nandan Banerjee](https://github.com/WPI-ARC/baxter/blob/master/baxter_ai_visi_planning/src/visi_plan.cpp)

---

Originally posted by [St3am](https://answers.ros.org/users/6506/st3am/) with karma: 170 on 2014-04-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Simon Schmeisser](https://answers.ros.org/users/21773/simon-schmeisser/) on 2015-06-11**:
I had to do

shapes::constructMsgFromShape(navstar_shape,navstar_mesh_msg);

navstar_mesh = boost::get<shape_msgs::Mesh>(navstar_mesh_msg);

**Comment by [fvd](https://answers.ros.org/users/8631/fvd/) on 2018-09-09**:
The includes for these commands are currently [here](https://github.com/ros-planning/geometric_shapes/tree/kinetic-devel/include/geometric_shapes).